# Почему кнопка ниже другой?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу написать CSS, который будет делать и `button` и `a` кнопками, похожими на material-дизайн. Написал стили, но если применить стили к элементу `a`, то он становится ниже `button` на один пиксель. Почему?

```css
.material-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #507299;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;

    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    white-space: nowrap;

    font-family: RobotoMedium;
    font-size: 14px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.material-button:hover,
.material-button:visited,
.material-button:link,
.material-button:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a role="button" class="material-button" >
  Запись
</a>

<button type="button" class="material-button" >
  Копировать
</button>
```

Comment: добавьте vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ещё верхний и нижний паддинг обнулите.
2. [Для файерфокса рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518143/6263942) обнулить паддинг и границу через `::-moz-focus-inner`. [В трюках советуют](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/) добавить `!important` и заключить инструкцию в `@-moz-document url-prefix(http://) { }`.

```css
/* 2. */
.material-button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 16px;
}        

.material-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #507299;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    
    /* 1. */
    padding: 0 16px;

    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    white-space: nowrap;

    font-family: RobotoMedium;
    font-size: 14px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.material-button:hover,
.material-button:visited,
.material-button:link,
.material-button:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a role="button" class="material-button" >
  Запись
</a>

<button type="button" class="material-button" >
  Копировать
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение проблемы =)

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, отметьте ответ как правильный

Comment: @ArchDemon так я и отметил, как только это стало возможно. Его же нельзя какое-то время после публикации вопроса принять.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, что в вашем вопросе, что в этом ответе кнопка Запись ниже кнопки Копировать. FF 47

Comment: @Visman, очень странно. Открыл вопрос в FF - тоже на 1 пиксель ниже. Открыл эти же кнопочки в своем проекте -  все нормально. Почему так получается - понятия не имею

Comment: @Visman и Илья, попробовал добавить паддингу `!important`, но нету FF под рукой. Посмотрите. пожалуйста, исправилось ли положение кнопок в FF?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, не изменилось положение в FF. А в IE11 все ок :)

Comment: @Visman Дополнил ответ инструкцией для файерфокса. Проверьте ещё раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, теперь в одну линию стоят.

Comment: @Visman Ура, спасибо за критику и за помощь!